# Peacock test implementation

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I would like to compare two 2D distributions statistically. Thus I would like to use the Peacock test (a 2D analogue of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test). There is an R package called [Peacock.test](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Peacock.tes) which claims to implement it.

But the documentation is quite sparse for this package, i.e.:

> The two functions: peacock2 and peacock3, provided in this package are self-explanatory and their usage is straightforward.

In particular I could not find what  the output of the `peacock()` function represents (I guess this is something like a p-value) ?
Has anyone has tested this function and could they tell me what it is (and if this function is reliable?)?

Usage example:

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(12, 0, 1), ncol=2)
y <-  matrix(rnorm(16, 0, 1), ncol=2)
ks <- peacock2(x, y)
ks
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it's reliable or not, but the code looks fairly straightforward.

Now the bad news: based on `?peacock2`, what the function gives you is

> *Value:*
>
> the value of the test statistic

This means that it is *not* giving you the p-value. The [original paper](http://mnras.oxfordjournals.org/content/202/3/615.full.pdf) ("Two-dimensional goodness-of-fit testing in astronomy",
JA Peacock, *Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society*, 1983), gives a table of critical values derived from Monte Carlo simulation, and an analytical approximation. To get a p-value from your test statistic, you'll have to (1) convert your test-statistic D into a Z statistic (section 3.5 says `Z=sqrt(n1*n2/(n1+n2))*D` for the two-sample test provided both n values are >10), and then suggests you can approximate this by `P(>Z)=2*exp(-2*(Z-0.5)^2)`.

I would **definitely** recommend reading the original paper and double-checking/deriving this for yourself if you intend to use it.

Comment: Thank you ! I am on my way to read this paper (without too much enthusiasm I must confess ) :)

Comment: The paper 'Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test For Two-Dimensional Data' by William H. Press and Saul A. Teukolsky or section 14.7 in their 'Numerical Recipes in C' give an a simple formula for the computation of significance level approximation which apparently works well for N >20.